# Can I access closed session Senate Foreign Relation Committee transcripts?

Tags: united-states, senate

A book I'm reading mentions a quote that supposedly comes from a closed session of the Senate Foreign Relation Committee meeting:

> Senator Albert Gore Sr., an ally of the administration, stated that they were a “provocation” in a closed session of the Senate Foreign Relations Committee in February 1961 (more than a year and a half before the missile crisis), adding, “I wonder what our attitude would be” if the Soviets deployed nuclear-armed missiles to Cuba.

Given the above information, I tried to search https://www.foreign.senate.gov/, but I couldn't find anything pertaining to a meeting in February 1961. Is it possible to find such documents?

Comment: Isn't that the point of a closed session?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt: I think he's looking for transcripts that are old enough to have been declassified and released.

Comment: I'm assuming they are released considering it was cited by the book.

Comment: @user7548189 - It could have been hearsay from another Senator.  I think this is a good question, but you might want to explicitly state that you're looking for _old_ transcripts, not current ones.

Comment: I suspect this one is part of the JFK Library collection. (Just a guess based on date and relation to the CMC)

Comment: I'm not sure (so not an answer), but you might look into the [Freedom of Information Act](https://oversight.house.gov/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Citizens-Guide-on-Using-FOIA.2012.pdf). Perhaps you could request old documents that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases, yes.

See the committee's 14 July 2010 press release [Senate Foreign Relations Committee Releases Volumes Of Previously Classified Transcripts From Vietnam Era Hearings](https://www.foreign.senate.gov/press/chair/release/senate-foreign-relations-committee-releases-volumes-of-previously-classified-transcripts-from-vietnam-era-hearings):

1175 pages of declassified transcripts:

https://www.foreign.senate.gov/press/chair/release/senate-foreign-relations-committee-releases-volumes-of-previously-classified-transcripts-from-vietnam-era-hearings

Also, in 2007 other transcripts were declassified:

https://fas.org/irp/congress/2007_hr/1967executive.html

More pertinent to 1961 may be [Executive sessions of the Senate Foreign Relations Committee](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/002754651)

Specifically [Volume XIII, part 1](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015012253541;view=1up;seq=3), 
is January-May 1961 transcripts made public in April of 1984.

And, yes, **on page 220 of the above-linked document, Gore speaking 28 February 1961 states**:

> I wonder what our attitude would be if warheads should be attached to missiles in Cuba.